# i need to make the date I not permitted to choose a date in the past by js?

Tags: javascript

I have an input field in booking form. the type of input is `type="date"`. I need to make it so that you cannot choose a date in the past, so I want the minimum date to be equal to today's date using javascript.

```
 <div class="go">
           <label>Going Date:</label> 
           <input type="date" id="goingDate" name="go" min="">
   </div> 

<script>
var mydate= new Date();
document.getElementByid("goingDate").min=mydate;
</script>
```

Comment: You should use a ready-made date picker, they have all sorts of options for this, like `allowPastDate = false`, things like that

Comment: Checkout the MDN article about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: can you give me an article about this.Jeremy Thille?

Comment: Simply google `javascript date picker` there's a lots of them ready to use out of the box